# IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 error in R.java when adding images!

Tags: android, intellij-idea, r.java-file

I create a new Android project in IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 (IC edition), register Android library and all goes fine. Then I add /drawable directory to /res directory and place an image inside of it. If I want to compile, I get an error.

[image]

When I navigate to these lines in R.java, I see just a simple auto-generated initializations.

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int img1=0x7f020002;
        public static final int img2=0x7f020003;
        public static final int icon=0x7f020004;
        public static final int img3=0x7f020005;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
        public static final int other=0x7f030001;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
    }
}
```

Anyone knows that this problem is? I am in the beginning of the project and I think I will return to 10.0.3 version.

Comment: It seems that this error appears when image name starts with a number, like 01.png. Is this an error or this name is forbidden in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the android limitation but java variable name one. It can not start with a number.